# Error con EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION en android

Tags: android, paypal

Estoy tratando de integrar la pasarela de pago a mi servicio en `android` pero al momento de ingresar `EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION` en mi codigo me aparece como si no existiera:

```
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,m_configuration);
```

¿alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar o con que lo puedo reemplazar?

Comment: Agrega tu código completo, PaymentActivity extiende de que clase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas accediendo a un Campo que no se tiene en la `Activity` (`PaymentActivity`), la cual no creo que extienda de `PayPalService`.

```
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,m_configuration);
```

[EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalService.html) es un campo del Servicio.

```
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
```

Para la implementación te sugiero veas este [ejemplo](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=DontPause-master/src/com/pierceholdings/dontpause/PaypalActivity.java):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

        Log.e(TAG, "Alert Dialog");

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Notice")
        .setMessage(this.getString(R.string.disclaimer))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok, I understand", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

                PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

            }

        })
       .setNegativeButton("Nevermind", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                PaypalActivity.this.finish();
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
```